# Microsoft Graph Add Favorites to Group - Mailbox move in Progress

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to set a group as a favorite for a member using the new v1.0 of the Microsoft Graph

**POST**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<id>/microsoft.graph.addFavorite
```

When doing the post I'm receiving the error

> "Mailbox move in progress. Try again later."

Has anyone seen this error and if so do you have a resolution?

Comment: Can you give it a try with `.../microsoft.graph.AddFavorite` (capital 'A')?

Comment: @mike Can you try this operation again, and see if it's working now or whether you are still getting this error please?  If you are please can you post the full error with the requestId and the timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

We've identified an issue causing that behavior for certain class of users. The issue has been resolved and you should no longer see that error when setting a group as favorite.